# No endpoint found for checksession using Azure B2C openid connect

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Would like to perform sessioncheck with azure B2C. So that I can check user session and perform a global signin and signoff. trying to implement a similar solution like the one provided for Azure AD https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out

But in my case CheckSessionIframe is null. There doesn't seem to be any endpoint in Azure B2C for checking usersession.

tenantSpecificConfig.CheckSessionIframe is null when I call the

OpenIdConnectConfiguration tenantSpecificConfig = await tenantSpecificOptions.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(notification.Request.CallCancelled);

[image]

Would like to know if Azure B2C has any such endpoint to check usersession?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C doesn't support `check_session`. However, it does allow a hidden frame to be used, to acquire new tokens from the `authorize` endpoint with the `prompt=none` parameter.

If this hidden request does succeed, then the end user has a current session at the Azure AD B2C service.